# How do I prevent .localized files from being created, the same way I can do with .DS_Store files?

Tags: terminal, finder

Mac creates a bundh of .localized files inside my folders. When I use the terminal they show everywhere. Is there a way to disable the creation of such files, the same way I can do it for the .DS_Store files?

Thanks!

Comment: How can you do that for .DS_Store files?